# Running Joomla 1.x website with Docker container

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I have Ubuntu 16.04 (host machine) with Nginx+PHP7+MySQL and a Docker container (docker) with PHP-FPM 5.6 installed. I want my Joomla 1.x website to run with PHP-FPM 5.6 in the Docker container, but use host's Nginx as the reverse proxy and host's MySQL. Where should I put PHP and static (HTML, js, png...) files in this configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP-FPM container needs access to all the source code. So you need to keep all code related stuff in that.

Nginx will proxy pass all PHP request to the FPM container. You would most probably server static files directly from NGINX. So you need to add those to the NGINX container. But I usually mount the static directory as a volume while running the container. So files can be updated easily